# Change ImageView

Tags: android, xml

I have set up an ImageView in main.xml, if I want to access it from my View class and make it visible = false, how can I do this programatically?

Thank you

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    theView = new GameView(this);
    theView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(theView);
```

Comment: This is not calling the layout i have for the main :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, in your layout xml file, there is a imageview1

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageview1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

in your java src,

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

you can google the difference between View.Gone and View.VISIBLE

Comment: This is great, one last question...I am doing all the code in the View class, but my correct layout shows with setContentView(R.layout.main) but I want the same layout to come up with setContentView(myView), how can i do this?

Comment: @user710502 make a layout file  myView.xml in layout folder, and then setContentView(R.layout.myView). Is this what you want?

Comment: would it still call all the elements of my class myView? if I do this?. Basically I have an Activity, in the activity I instantiate and do this public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); theView = new GameView(this); theView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.main); setContentView(theView); But it doesnt show the layout, it comes back with a black screen.   If i do setContentView(R.layout.main) only then it shows but the OnTouch event from myView wont work

Answer (score 1):

First you should retrieve a link to this view object. Than set visibility property of this object to `View.INVISIBLE`

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this property in the xml of that Imageview

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

and change the visibility programatically like this on some particular event:

```
image.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE)
```

where image is the instance of that imageview received  through **findViewById()**

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.setVisibility (android.View.INVISIBLE);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have  a `ImageView` called `imageView`.

Now access the `imageView` like

```
imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
```

Now when you are trying to hide the `imageView` just use `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Hope this will help you

Comment: Yes all of you guys are great :)